# PHP get string from line number

Tags: php

I am using php to get the contents of a webpage:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('http://insertwebsitenamehere.com');
```

Is there a way to seek a line number andreturn the line at that location?

I know you can use [SplFileObject::Seek](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.seek.php) if the fileContent is a *file*. Can I perform something similar without the need to turn it into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [file()](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) instead

```
$fileContent = file('http://insertwebsitenamehere.com');
echo $fileContent[39]; //line 40
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank-you!